# How to sort files in a directory by name, size, last modified or other OS supported?

Tags: java, sorting

Does java have underlying or direct method to sort files in a directory by name, size, last modified or other OS supported?

Common way to sort files is: read all file info in a container, than sort elements of that container.

But I want to know, does java provide some APIs which is native or invoke system call to sort directly? Maybe OS or underlying file system can provide better method? is there?

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107001/how-can-i-sort-files-in-a-directory-in-java/30893390#30893390

Comment: @khAn that won't help OP because it obviously sorts within Java.

Comment: @khAn  Thx but that use stream.sorted, it obviously read all entries and sorts in heap memory..

Comment: OS do not have sistem call which sort files. If you ask `ls` or `dir` sorted list it get whole list from os and sort it.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31259085/programmatically-sort-folders-on-windows-8

Comment: @talex that sounds bad! how should I store whole file list if files number is very big even greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE? Maybe I must create and buffer a long-size container, start a file watch service :(

Comment: how you want to use this sorted files? Are you sure that you need them sorted? If it is unavoidable I suggest to use some external sort on files.

Comment: Files itself do not have any order inside a directory. The *ordering* comes from the application you are viewing the directory with, on windows for example the **Explorer.exe**. There are no *system calls* in Java to talk to the *explorer*. There may be some libraries out there though, don't know.